# create dijit.Tree with JsonStore and the C# mvc controller that provides the data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jsonstore, dijit.tree

How can I add a tree of entities at client that are fetched from server through JSON ?

I have a basic asp.net mvc3 site written in C# at VS2012. For now I'm running the site in IIS 7 Express on windows 7 on my local machine.

I have found a dijit.Tree element that can be used to represent entities at client with underlying model and JsonStore. I tried to connect that JSONStore to the server's Controller. But the tree still is not visible at the browser. I have checked with Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m and IExplorer x64  ver. 9.

I need some full example with a basic (C#) entity like:

```
class RestfulEntity
{
  public string id;
  public string name;
  public string description;
}
```

I have looked at:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/Tree-examples

[MVC3 RESTful API Routing & Http Verb Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610451/mvc3-restful-api-routing-http-verb-handling)

[http://blog.respondify.se/2011/09/using-dijit-tree-with-the-new-dojo-object-store/]
[//http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx]
[//http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331920/Connecting-Dojo-DataGrid-to-Entity-Framework-4-1-u]
[//http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
[Tree View with "CRUD operations", "drag and drop (DnD)" and "Lazy Loading" using Dojo Tree, Entity Framework, SQL Server, ASP.NET MVC,JsonRest](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337439/Tree-View-with-CRUD-operations-drag-and-drop-DnD-a)
I hope it helps.